# filter by first foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, foreign-keys, eloquent

I am creating a website to compare product prices in different stores. I have set up a database with these two tables.

```
+---------+     +------------+
| Product |     | Price      |
+---------+     +------------+
| id      |     | id         |
| name    |     | product_id |
+---------+     | price      |
                | date       |
                +------------+
```

Now I would like to be able to get all the products where the last `price.date` is earlier than a certain date.

I have tried using the following code, but without success.

```
Product::with(['prices' => function($q){
    $q->first()->where('date', '<', Carbon::yesterday());
}])->get()->prices();
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not sure what that `first()` is doing in there, and if it needs to be in there why it's towards the beginning of the query? It'll return a result or null, so you can't chain `->where()` onto it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`With()` is only for eager loading records.

You need to use `whereHas`:

`Product::whereHas('price',function($q) {
    return $q->where('date', '<', Carbon::yesterday());
})->whereHas('price',function($q) {
   return $q->where('date','>=',Carbon::yesterday());
},'=',0)->get();`

This will return all products `where` it `has` prices whose `date` is `less` than `Carbon::yesterday()`

[Official Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

Comment: Won't this try all records? I would like to have all products that have not yet had a price after yesterday.

Comment: No it won't. This doesn't eager load the `price` table. Instead it does a `where (select count(*) from price where date < 'yesterday'  and product_id = product.id) > 0`

Comment: To see what queries are being run by eloquent. Add a `toSql()` at the end of the query (instead of `get()`), and dump it.

Comment: Yes, but when this product has a price from a month ago and a price from today, it will still be selected because it will find a date older than yesterday. I want to find all products which don't have a price before yesterday. Every product has multiple prices.

Comment: I see your point. Changed my answer. It will show all products who has a price before yesterday and who don't have a price after yesterday.

Comment: do you know if it is possible to exclude the price table from the results collection?

Comment: The price table won't be loaded with the query provided above. Check if your eloquent model doesn't eager load the `price` table by default? (Look for the attribute `$with` in your eloquent model)